# Trouble Getting OpenLayers Examples (with jQuery) Working in jsFiddle

Tags: openlayers, jsfiddle

I'm finding it quite frustrating to figure out why OpenLayers is failing to load for me.  Ultimately, I want to run it on a single page in Drupal, so it needs to work with jQuery.  There are some examples in jsFiddle, but not many.

The closest I've come is http://jsfiddle.net/3A8Zn/ - but when I bring that over to Drupal I don't get the navigational elements displayed the same way.

In most instances, even though I'm copying from other examples that I can see working, in attempting to bring them over to jsFiddle they break somewhere:

- http://jsfiddle.net/dPdhZ/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Bbtxz/
- http://jsfiddle.net/MS6Bn/
- http://jsfiddle.net/kPQfw/
- http://jsfiddle.net/WfCUs/
- http://jsfiddle.net/sVABD/

Maybe jsFiddle doesn't actually respect:  
Possibly me forcing everything to single quotes is breaking something.

Any ideas on why these aren't working in jsFiddle would be appreciated.  There seem to be a lot of possible points of failure.

EDIT: Got a good response here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23103/getting-openlayers-working-in-jsfiddle/23115#23115